# InvocationContext.proceed() exceptions?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, interceptor

Does the proceed() method of javax.interceptor.InvocationContext ever throw any exceptions other than those from the target method or intervening code? How about InvocationTargetException? Documentation, generally, seems incomplete on this point.

[EDIT] I am asking: is the InvocationTargetException what is 'ordinarily' thrown by implementors of InvocationContext? Or is the original exception usually re-thrown? Or something else?

The 'throws' declaration allows all exceptions, of course, but I wonder what the 'contract' is? A natural contract would be to leave exceptions from the invoked target method unchanged. This cannot be expressed in the Java type system, of course. And it is not documented or anything. So, in principle, *any* exception could be thrown. An exception from the target method could in principle be wrapped any which way; not just InvocationTargetException.

This definitely has architectural consequences. If there is no 'contract' for the implementations of InvocationContext, the exception system will become nearly useless; essentially, all we will be able to know is that there has been an exception. So I am asking about such a 'contract', i.e. expected behavior of the implementations: is there one?

Answer (score 0):

- At runtime compiler is unable to analyze the method calls through reflection, therefore it wraps them up into exception called `InvocationTargetException`.

  > An InvocationTargetException is thrown when a constructor called
  >   through Constructor.newInstance(), or a method called through
  >   Method.invoke() throws an exception. The InvocationTargetException
  >   encapsulates the thrown exception, which can be retrieved using
  >   getTargetException().

  You have to unwrap this exception to get the original root cause.
- As documented, `InvocationContext.proceed()` throws `java.lang.Exception`. It further calls to the other interceptors in the line of invocation.

  I haven't encountered any issues with it, but may occur when nested interceptors are used & one of the interceptor throws exception, can lead to chain of cascading exceptions.

Comment: So are you saying that in your experience, all you have to do to recover the original exception is to unwrap the InvocationTargetException? And in one step only?

Comment: @JonasN You can unwrap it to retrieve original exception by `e.getCause()`

Comment: I know that. What I want to know is if it's always (supposed to be) 'InvocationTargetException'? I could be wrapped in any way, or not at all. Or it could vary.

Comment: @JonasN It depends where it is encountered & how the compiler handles it. If there is some problem during invocation of some method, then it may wrap that exception into `InvocationTargetException`.